# What does @ character in PHP exactly do?

Tags: php

for example in strip_tags you can use like this:

string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

but I wondering if it could be use like this:

@strip_tags

and What's the difference?.
Thanks

Comment: It's an error suppressor.

Comment: ^^^ aka skips the error and continues executing code.

Comment: It resets the error_reporting level for the following expression. (The *default* error handler then omits the output. Logging or custom handlers may not.)

Answer (score 0):

It is an Error Control Operator.

See here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php